# n.times do returns value of n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

I have a problem with my code, I want it to display n number of stars. It display the right number of stars,  plus the integer  like `***3`I only want `***`

**show.html.slim**

```
= article.rating_average.times do
  span
  i.fa.fa-star
```

Comment: Just change = to -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `=` to `-`:

```
- article.rating_average.times do
  %span.fa.fa-star
```

- `=` evaluates code *and* prints the returned value (`3` is a return value of `article.rating_average.times {}`)
- `-` just evaluates code (gives you 3 stars without the returned value printed)

Comment: how could I miss this !!
Thanks a lot :)